# Optimize the Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query which takes lots of time for the execution. I don't know how to optimize this. Can anyone help me on this.

```
SELECT
    s.eventday as eventday,
    SUM(s.recipients) as totalrecipients,
    SUM(greatest(s.rcpt - s.recipients, 0)) as totalbounces,
    SUM(s.traphits) as totaltraphits,
    toUInt32(round(sum(toDecimal64(s.recipients, 0) * s.complaintrate) / 100, 0)) AS totalcomplaints,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.filter = 'GREEN' THEN s.recipients ELSE 0 END) AS green,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.filter = 'YELLOW' THEN s.recipients ELSE 0 END) AS yellow,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.filter = 'RED' THEN s.recipients ELSE 0 END) AS red
FROM 
    (SELECT
        f.ip,
        f.filter,
        f.eventday,
        MAX(f.recipients) as recipients,
        MAX(f.rcpt) as rcpt,
        MAX(f.traphits) as traphits,
        MAX(f.complaintrate) as complaintrate
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            snds.ip,
            snds.filter,
            snds.eventday,
            MAX(snds.recipients) as recipients,
            MAX(snds.rcpt) as rcpt,
            MAX(snds.traphits) as traphits,
            MAX(snds.complaintrate) as complaintrate
         FROM monitor.sndsdata snds
         WHERE snds.eventday >= :startdate 
           AND snds.eventday <= :enddate 
           AND snds.snds_id in (:snds_id)
        GROUP BY snds.ip, snds.filter, snds.eventday) f
    GROUP BY f.ip, f.filter, f.eventday) s
GROUP BY 
    s.eventday
ORDER BY 
    s.eventday
```

Actually I am new to MySQL, so I don't have any idea on this. I think the above query have most subqueries that's why it takes a lot of time to run.

Comment: What you need is to look at execution plan of the query. That will tell you costs of each step of the query and maybe suggest some actions (partitioning the table, adding index etc.). If you are using MySQL Bench, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-tutorial-visual-explain-dbt3.html. if you are using other MySQL tools, search for "Explain" or "Explain and Analyze" for that tool.

Comment: Remove excess nested subquery.

Comment: @bracko can you provide a sample code for the query. Which helps a lot.. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone provide a sample code for the query. Which helps a lot.. Thanks!

Comment: As already suggested by Akina, you should remove the unnecessary nested subquery, leaving the outer query and innermost subquery. It would help if you added the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `sndsdata`, a small amount of sample data ([markdown table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)) and the `EXPLAIN` output for your query.